# How to Capture Images continuously and faster

Tags: image, mobile, java-me, nokia

I am developing an application in J2ME which have to processes images continuously taken from mobile camera. Its purpose is to detect the movement of the mobile and move an object on the screen. i am using

`videoControl.getSnapshot("encoding=png&width=100&height=100");`

to take images. But the problem is that it is taking about 4 sec to capture next image. It is very slow process.
Is there any way to get image faster?

Since mobile camera has 15 fps Video Recording Frame Rate, Cant we use that capability to capture images faster?

Currently I am targeting for Nokia E5 (target can be changed if not supported.)

Comment: I have tested with nokia mobiles and always it is very slow, i don't know if is possible capture faster

Comment: how do you create the videoControl?

Comment: @GorkemErcan

player = Manager.createPlayer("capture://video"); 
player.realize(); 
videoControl = (VideoControl) (player.getControl("VideoControl"));